# Plotly express line charts plots differently (all over the plane)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Hi all I am currently developing a django web app, I have used plotly (python package not the django-plotly) to do the graphing. On my development environment my charts work fine like below,
[image]

But when I clone my repositery and run it on different machine graphs look like this,
[image]

Following are my configurations,

- I use Mongodb and x axis values are as type string
- Tested on both windows and a centos machine still get the  below wired looking graph
- I pass the data as a list of dictionaries (not as a dataframe)
- Added plotly js library in static files (I dont see a effect on this)

```
def lineGraph(response):
  fig = px.line(response, x="trans_date", y="total_withdrawal", title='Total Withdrawals', template="plotly_dark")
  fig.data[-1].name = "Withdrawals"
  return plot(fig, output_type='div')
```

First 5 elements:

```
[{'unit_id': 2, 'trans_date': '2017-01-03', 'branch': 'test', 'total_withdrawal': 4100}, {'unit_id': 2, 'trans_date': '2017-01-09', 'branch': 'test', 'total_withdrawal': 18300}, 
{'unit_id': 2, 'trans_date': '2017-01-14', 'branch': 'test', 'total_withdrawal': 20000}, {'unit_id': 2, 'trans_date': '2017-01-17', 'branch': 'test', 'total_withdrawal': 800}, {'unit_id': 2, 'trans_date': '2017-01-18', 'branch': 'test', 'total_withdrawal': 158800}]
```

Comment: Sort your dataframe by `trans_date` first.

Comment: I was trying not to go with dataframes, but still without sorting i get the graphs correctly on my machine

Comment: in this case converting `trans_date` to datetime should help.